# exploded or compact storage format for cached orthophotos?

Tags: arcgis-server, cache, mapcache

I cached 2 map services.One of them was cached using exploded option and the other map was  cached using compact.
The same scales were cached for both maps.
I am wondering about a method to calculate the performance / speed for each one, so I can choose which cached map can be used later.

[image]

Comment: Performance/Speed of how long it takes to cache or how quick to render for a user?

Comment: How quick to render for a user?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What is the advantages of using exploded option?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Server [Log Parse](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=90134fb0f1c148a48c65319287dde2f7)r should help you in this regard. Try to hit both services independently and then use the log parser to see the response times.

The compact format should deliver [better performance](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/inside-the-compact-cache-storage-format.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_106C288A03514CE480CE5FE0A9027186) compared to the exploded format since that is what it was designed for.